# How to shutdown EC2 instances backed by ECS to save the cost for staging/QA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We have hosted a docker container on AWS ECS with EC2 instances and would like to terminate/showdown these EC2 instances in the night & weekend for Staging/QA to save the cost.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the instances in an **AutoScaling Group** (ASG) , you could use [scheduled policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html) to set a **desired capacity** of the ASG to zero for the off-peak times. A second policy would start it for work time.

Alternative would be setup a [CloudWatch Event scheduled rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) using `cron` with target of  lambda function. The function would do same as the scaling policy. But because this is lambda function, you could also do some other things there. For example, do some pre-shutdown checks or post-shutdown cleanup.

This will work, because if your tasks run in service, ECS will **automatically relaunch** your tasks when the instances are back.

You could also manage the number of tasks using [scheduling capability of Amazon ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html).

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Instance Scheduler is a simple AWS-provided solution that enables customers to easily configure custom start and stop schedules for their Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) and Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) instances. The solution is easy to deploy and can help reduce operational costs for both development and production environments.

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/